# Delete post (that I created) from friends wall

Tags: api, facebook-opengraph

As far as I understand Facebook allowes you (through the API) to post on your friends wall.

Is it possible to delete that post (if I created it) just like I can delete a post to my own wall?

If yes how do I go about it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple - Make a HTTP DELETE request to `https://graph.facebook.com/{POST_ID_HERE}?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`

The access token needs the publish_stream permission as far as I know, and the Post needs to have been posted with the same app that generated the token.

Comment: It needs my publish_stream permission (Not the friends) correct?

Comment: Yes - again, i really must be clear on this, you can only delete content **which was posted by the same app**